# How do i send whatsapp message thorugh my python script for developers

Tags: python, api, whatsapp

I have been trying this for a long time but i couldn't be able to find the any free way excepting 
twilio sms gateway and selenium.
I want to integrate whatsapp send message api in my python script.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple hack using which you can do this in a easy way, I did it without using selenium, because in selenium it doesn't stores cache and old cookies, so you can use below ans

you just need to get a link like this

`url='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=91XXXXXXXXXX&text='+msg`

Install whatsapp desktop, for first time, click in browsers allow all the times to open in application

Now you can hit this URL using python and press enter

install keyboard via pip

use this

```
import os
import sys
msg=' '.join(sys.argv[1:(len(sys.argv))])
import webbrowser

url='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=91XXXXXXXXXX&text='+msg
webbrowser.register('edge',
    None,
    webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"))
webbrowser.get('edge').open(url)
import keyboard as k
import time
time.sleep(10)
k.press_and_release('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest WhatsApp messages cannot be sent since whatsapp doesn't allow programatic access except via paid versions.

Refer [Programatic Access for WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api)

I remember using [yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) couple of 3 years back. I believe this project is obsolete now. I haven't been following this for quite some time.

I recommend the usage of Telegram bots for getting automated triggers if that serves your purpose.

Happy Coding.