# Send WhatsApp message every 24 hours

Tags: python, whatsapp

I want to send a WhatsApp message every 24 hours automatically using python, with the pywhatkit library. Here is the code I got so far:

```
import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+91xxxxxxxxxx", "Hello, world", 16, 00)
```

Send every 24 hours adaptation:

```
import pywhatkit
import time
   
while True:
    time.sleep(86400) #86400 seconds in a day
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+91xxxxxxxxxx","Hello, world", 16, 00)
```

I would have to keep my PC on 24/7 for this to work. Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: When researching for this, WhatsApp is the part that's irrelevant, unless it has a builtin solution. So, what would be keywords for a search? Something like "schedule", "regular" or "daily". Perhaps, you could even find a solution that doesn't require Python but can be used for any program.

Comment: I want to find a better way of doing it that just using `time.sleep(86400)`

Comment: you need to use host application on server like heroku and put your code in it and run it

Answer (score 0):

See you can use pywhatkit, and can add a loop using python library like this you can get hours

```
from datetime import datetime

# datetime object containing current date and time
now = datetime.now()
 
import time

time.strftime('%X') // '13:12:47'

time.strftime('%x') // '01/20/22'

time.strftime('%d') // '20' day

time.strftime('%m') // '01' month

time.strftime('%y') // '20' year

time.strftime('%H') // '01' hour

time.strftime('%M') // '01' minute

time.strftime('%m') // '01' second
```

but I **recommend** instead of pywhatkit use this, this is very fast and never misses,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71168835/6236959